# Efficiently testing for more zeros than ones in a binary code block

Tags: probability, information-theory, sampling-theory

**Setting**. I have a set $\mathcal{C}$ of binary sequences where each sequence has length $L\in \mathbb{N}$ and the total number of sequences in $\mathcal{C}$ is $N\in \mathbb{N}$. Assume that $N=\exp(O(L))$.

Assume that the only way elements of $\mathcal{C}$ can be viewed/accessed is via calls to a function $\Theta : \{0,1\}^{L}\rightarrow \{0,1\}^L$ that takes as input any binary sequence $s$ of length $L$ and returns the element in $\mathcal{C}$ closest in Hamming distance to $s$ (ties are broken arbitrarily).

Further, suppose that the number of zeros and ones in $\mathcal{C}$ (in total across all sequences) are such that #zeros=2 $\times$ #ones *or* #ones=2 $\times$ #zeros (i.e. there are either twice more zeros than ones *or* twice more ones than zeros).

**Goal**. I want a procedure which chooses a sequence $s_1,\dots,s_K\in \{0,1\}^L$ of inputs to the function $\Theta$ to test whether {#zeros $\geq $#ones in $\mathcal{C}$} with a given confidence level $\delta \in(0,1)$.

**Question**. Does there exist a procedure for which the required ''sample size'' $K$ to achieve the above goal is polynomial in $L$ (rather than exponential)?

Comment: ???  You are supposing there are more zeros than ones in $\mathcal C$.  So if your procedure is to test whether there are more zeros than ones in $\mathcal C$ should just return "yes".

Comment: I edited my question to clarify this point.

Comment: Does $\exp(O(L))$ mean $O(e^L)$ ?

Comment: Are you after an answer in a probabilistic sense ? If yes you should tell us something about the distribution of the sequences in $\mathcal C$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I would think that $\exp(O(L))$ means bounded by $\exp(ML)$ for some positive constant $M$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yes, exp(()) means bounded by exp() for some positive constant $M$; in this case $M < \log 2 $.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I am after an answer in the probabilistic sense, but I do not want to make any assumptions about the distribution of the sequences in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Also please consider that people might be in different time zones before concluding "the OP is not willing to answer".

Comment: Even without considering time zones, nobody should be expected to be monitoring MSE every day.  Some people have lives...

Comment: Without a distribution, a probabilistic answer is not possible.

Comment: If you think this is the case, could you please provide a formal counter-example?

Comment: @user6952886 "Assume that $N = \exp(O(L))$". Isn't that meaningless? Obviously $N \le \exp(L\log 2)$...

Comment: @mathworker21 I think the OP clarified in one of the comments that the constant $M< \log 2$. Although I think this assumption is not too informative either.

Answer (score 0):

Each call $y = \Theta (x)$ gives you a value $y \in \mathcal{C}$.

The formula for determining sample size $n$ to estimate the proportion of successes in a dichotomous outcome variable (yes/no) in a single population:

$$n = p\bigg(1 - p\bigg)\bigg({Z \over E}\bigg)^2$$

where,

$Z$ is the value from the standard normal distribution reflecting the confidence level that will be used *(e.g., $Z = 1.96$ for $95\%$)*,

$E$ is the desired margin of error,

$p$ is the proportion of successes in the population

So, $n$ depends on the experiment parameters $Z, E$ and the estimated proportion of successes only. If you don't know the estimate, use $p = 0.5$ to calculate $n$.

Then your procedure is to test random sample of size $n = \{ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \}$ and check $y_i = \Theta (x_i)$ for number of ones and zeroes.

If you use $Z = 1.96$ for $95\%$ Confidence Interval and Margin of Error $(E)$ of $5\%$, you need to sample

$$n = 0.5\bigg(1 - 0.5\bigg)\bigg({1.96 \over 0.05}\bigg)^2 = 384.16$$

So, you should sample at least 384 binary sequences from $\mathcal{C}$

Note that $\log_2 (384.16) \approx 8.59$. So, for binary sequences of length 8 bit or less, you need to do 100% sampling.

Obviously, this sample size is dependent only on the experiment parameters and will change  with it.

Also, this does not change whether you are checking for zeroes or ones because the factor $p(1-p)$ is symmetric.

Comment: What is your definition of a ``success''?

Comment: You are trying to determine if $N$ binary sequences are biased (i.e, with more $0$s than $1$s). As I mentioned in the answer, if $p$ represents the proportion of $1$s, then $p(1-p) = k$. If $p$ represents the proportion of $0$s, then also $p(1-p) = k$. For a given bias of $p$ (towards 0 or 1), the factor $p(p-1)$ is the same.

So, success is being able to say within the confidence level afforded by the sample size $K$ and within the margin of error whether the sequences are biased or not.

Comment: You can never be 100% sure, unless you test all $N$ sequences. Even then, you cannot conclude bias. There is an infinitesimal probability that it could be by chance unless $N = 2^L$ and you tested all $N$.